# PHP AMQP consumer: Server channel error: 404, message: NOT_FOUND

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm using the amqp extension in pecl 1.0.3, compiled with 2.7.1 rabbitmq.

I'm trying to get a basic consumer/producer example working, but I keep getting errors. There's very little php documentation on this extension and a lot of it seemed to be outdated or wrong.

I used the code a user posted, but can't seem to get the consumer part working

Connection:

```
function amqp_connection() {
    $amqpConnection = new AMQPConnection();
    $amqpConnection->setLogin("guest");
    $amqpConnection->setPassword("guest");
    $amqpConnection->connect();

    if(!$amqpConnection->isConnected()) {
       die("Cannot connect to the broker, exiting !\n");
    }

    return $amqpConnection;
}
```

Sender:

```
function amqp_send($text, $routingKey, $exchangeName){
    $amqpConnection = amqp_connection();

    $channel = new AMQPChannel($amqpConnection);
    $exchange = new AMQPExchange($channel);

    $exchange->setName($exchangeName);
    $exchange->setType("fanout");


    if($message = $exchange->publish($text, $routingKey)){
       echo "sent";
    }

    if (!$amqpConnection->disconnect()) {
        throw new Exception("Could not disconnect !");
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
function amqp_receive($exchangeName, $routingKey, $queueName) {
    $amqpConnection = amqp_connection();

    $channel = new AMQPChannel($amqpConnection);
    $queue = new AMQPQueue($channel);
    $queue->setName($queueName);
    $queue->bind($exchangeName, $routingKey);

    //Grab the info
    //...
}
```

Then sending it:

```
amqp_send("Abcdefg", "action", "amq.fanout");
```

And Receiving it:

```
amqp_receive("amq.fanout","action","action");
```

I keep getting a problem running the script and points to the amqp receive:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'AMQPQueueException' with message 'Server channel error: 404, message: NOT_FOUND - no queue 'action' in vhost '/'' in /home/jamescowhen/test.php:21

Can anyone point me to the right direction? The whole sample is from a user note here: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqp.examples.php#109024

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception seems to be caused by your queue not being declared (as the error message describes 404 - the queue 'action' was not found). The reason why the example works for the original poster is probably because he already has declared the queue earlier, without realizing that it's missing in his example.

You can declare the queue by calling ->declare() on the queue object. You'll also have to do this with the exchange object, unless you're certain that it already exists when you attempt to hook the queue onto it.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I originally used a php library instead of the native extension, by default that library made the queue if it were not declare already.